# Failed creating bean flywayInitializer - SpringBoot 2.3.0

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, h2, flyway

I am trying to migrate a project from spring boot 2.0.0 to 2.3.0 with H2 database and Hibernate and I keep getting an error
on bean creation for flywayInitializer:

```
2020-11-20 14:05:51.999  INFO 4632 --- [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-11-20 14:05:53.125  INFO 4632 --- [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-11-20 14:05:53.157  INFO 4632 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration     : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:D:/Workspace/username/projectName_db/projectName_db'
2020-11-20 14:05:53.313  INFO 4632 --- [           main] w.s.s.SecurityFilterProviderCollection   : using 'waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider'
2020-11-20 14:05:53.453  INFO 4632 --- [           main] s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource :  URL 'ldaps://0200P-CDC201.banst-s.banst-pt.int:636/', root DN is ''
2020-11-20 14:05:53.641  INFO 4632 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.RegistrationBean               : Filter negotiateSecurityFilter was not registered (disabled)
2020-11-20 14:05:53.922  INFO 4632 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.l.VersionPrinter                 : Flyway Community Edition 6.4.1 by Redgate
2020-11-20 14:05:53.953  INFO 4632 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.d.DatabaseFactory                : Database: jdbc:h2:D:/Workspace/username/projectName_db/projectName_db (H2 1.4)
2020-11-20 14:05:54.203  INFO 4632 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.c.DbMigrate                      : Current version of schema "FLAYWAY": 1.18.0
2020-11-20 14:05:54.219  WARN 4632 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Schema "FLAYWAY" contains a failed migration to version 1.18.0 !
2020-11-20 14:05:54.219  INFO 4632 --- [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-11-20 14:05:54.266  INFO 4632 --- [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-11-20 14:05:54.282  INFO 4632 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-11-20 14:05:54.297  INFO 4632 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
    
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2020-11-20 14:05:54.328 ERROR 4632 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Schema "FLAYWAY" contains a failed migration to version 1.18.0 !
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Schema "FLAYWAY" contains a failed migration to version 1.18.0 !
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:227) ~[flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:?]
        ... 19 more
```

My application.yml has the following configurations

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
  jackson:
    serialization:
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    database: default
    show-sql: false
  quartz:
    job-store-type: memory
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
  flyway:
    locations: "classpath:database/projectName/migrations/{vendor}/"
    schemas: "FLAYWAY"
    table: "schema_version"
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    validate-on-migrate: false
```

Does anyone know what I can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The error states that there is a failed migration:

```
Schema "FLAYWAY" contains a failed migration to version 1.18.0 !
```

Try deleting the failed entry and run again.

Or try to run:

```
mvn flyway:validate -Dflyway.configFile=myFlywayConfig.properties
```

to validate everything first.